# Using a delay to redirect after ASP.NET AJAX Submit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I've got a log in page, which upon submission of the login form, displays some information to the user for a couple of seconds before redirecting to the target page.

This was working fine with a timed refresh as follows:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH","3;URL=test.aspx");
```

However, I've now installed ASP.NET AJAX and have put the submit button into an UpdatePanel which gets the callback via AJAX and displays the information to the user. This is all done in the login.aspx.vb code behind file.

The timed refresh no longer works. I assume this is because I am doing a partial refresh and therefore adding a header to the page won't work... I assume

Is there any other way of doing this without adding more Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add some JavaScript to perform the page refresh.  You assumed correctly; the page header to refresh will not work if you're only doing a partial update.  If you register a client script in your postback to do the refresh, that should work OK.

Comment: Thanks. I'd kind of assumed I was going to have to go that way, just wanted to avoid client side JavaScript on it, ah well!

Comment: Um... now I feel like I'm being really dumb... it won't work! I've made a div called "redirect" in the UpdatePanel and trying to insert a Javascript redirect into it, but it does nothing. The redirect code is: 
`redirect.InnerHtml = "<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout('window.location.href = 'index.aspx'',1000)</script>"`

Comment: Grrr... got it working!
`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, GetType(UpdatePanel), "redirectIt", "function doThis(){window.location.href = 'index.aspx'}; setTimeout('doThis()','" & redirectTime & "')", True)`